# Copy all the Values to another Column based on Condition

Tags: pivot-table, powerpivot

I have Text Column called "PASS" in Pivot table holding values like and NA and 0.0133333333333333 .
So I want to create the calculate column "CALS "and copy all the values which are not holding NA into this CALS column and set value 0 if found NA.Can any one help me how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's the use case for this, but a simple IF should do:

```
=IF([PASS]="NA", 0, [PASS])
```

This puts 0 if value in *PASS* column is "NA", if not, then it copies the numeric value.